# I am coming from Uganda and traveling to Swaziland but will take a bus from Johannesburg to Swaziland. Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: air-travel, transit, johannesburg, rwanda, ugandan-citizens

Am traveling to Swaziland by bus but coming in through Johannesburg. Do I need a transit visa? I am from Uganda.

Answer (score 2):

You require a South African tourist visa since you will be entering South Africa at OR Tambo International Airport and then catching a bus to Eswatini (Swaziland).

For other interested persons, Swaziland has changed the official name to Eswatini.

Comment: According to the South African Department of Home Affairs, [a transit visa is for "foreigners en-route to the neighbouring countries."](http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/types-of-visas)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IATA Travel Center,](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com) as a Ugandan citizen, you will need a visa for South Africa.  The only way to avoid requiring a visa is if you are flying in and out of South Africa.

> ### Visa South Africa
>
> Visa required.
>
> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers transiting through Cape Town (CPT), Durban (DUR), Johannesburg (JNB) or Lanseria (HLA) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Comment: This doesn't address whether a transit visa is adequate or a "holiday" visa (as they seem to be called) is required.  I find the relevant South African government pages confusing, which is why I haven't posted an answer myself.